# Matplotlib - Delete lines from a 3d quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to graphically represent the time trend of a three-dimensional reference frame using Matplotlib and the quiver function. In an event, I simulated the data representing the reference frame through the definition of a 3x3 rotation matrix. Each time the event occurs, it should delete the previous reference frame and display the new one. Here is my code in Python:

```
import random as rnd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def timerTick_Event(i):
   #%% DATA SIMULATION
   temp1 = np.array([rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)]).astype(float)
   temp1 = temp1 / np.linalg.norm(temp1)
   
   v2 = np.array([rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)]).astype(float)
   v2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)
   
   v3 = np.cross(temp1, v2)
   v3 = v3 / np.linalg.norm(v3)
   
   v1 = np.cross(v2, v3)
   v1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)    
       
   mat = np.column_stack((v1, v2, v3))
   
   
   #%% DATA REPRESENTATION
   f = plt.gcf()
   ax = f.gca()    


   #INSERT DELETE FUNCTION HERE


   u = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, mat[0,0], mat[0,1], mat[0,2], color="r")
   v = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, mat[1,0], mat[1,1], mat[1,2], color="g")
   w = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, mat[2,0], mat[2,1], mat[2,2], color="b")
    
   plt.show()


f1 = plt.figure(1)
ax = f1.add_subplot(projection='3d')

u = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, color="r")
v = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, color="g")
w = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, color="b")
# set empty line plots with colors associate to the
# quivers. Doing so we can show a legend.
ax.plot([], [], [], color="r", label="X")
ax.plot([], [], [], color="g", label="Y")
ax.plot([], [], [], color="b", label="Z")

ax.set_xlim(-1.1, 1.1); ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1); ax.set_zlim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax.set_xlabel("X_AXIS"); ax.set_ylabel("Y_AXIS"); ax.set_zlabel("Z_AXIS")
ax.legend();



timerTickInterval = 1000
ani = FuncAnimation(f1, timerTick_Event, interval=timerTickInterval)
plt.show()
```

This code works fine except for the missing delete function. In a 2d plot, I used this code to delete annotations

```
for child in ax.get_children():
        if isinstance(child, mTxt.Annotation):
            child.remove()
```

and this command to delete the first plotted line

```
ax.lines.pop(0)
```

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep track of the quiver artists, you can use them to remove the previously plotted quivers:

```
import random as rnd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

quivers_artist = []

def timerTick_Event(i):
    global quivers_artist
    #%% DATA SIMULATION
    temp1 = np.array([rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)]).astype(float)
    temp1 = temp1 / np.linalg.norm(temp1)
    v2 = np.array([rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)]).astype(float)
    v2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)
    v3 = np.cross(temp1, v2)
    v3 = v3 / np.linalg.norm(v3)
    v1 = np.cross(v2, v3)
    v1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)    
    mat = np.column_stack((v1, v2, v3))
    #%% DATA REPRESENTATION
    f = plt.gcf()
    ax = f.gca()    
    #INSERT DELETE FUNCTION HERE
    if len(quivers_artist) > 0:
        for q in quivers_artist:
            q.remove()
        quivers_artist.clear()
    quivers_artist.append(ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, mat[0,0], mat[0,1], mat[0,2], color="r"))
    quivers_artist.append(ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, mat[1,0], mat[1,1], mat[1,2], color="g"))
    quivers_artist.append(ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, mat[2,0], mat[2,1], mat[2,2], color="b"))


f1 = plt.figure(1)
ax = f1.add_subplot(projection='3d')

u = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, color="r")
v = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, color="g")
w = ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, color="b")
# set empty line plots with colors associate to the
# quivers. Doing so we can show a legend.
ax.plot([], [], [], color="r", label="X")
ax.plot([], [], [], color="g", label="Y")
ax.plot([], [], [], color="b", label="Z")

ax.set_xlim(-1.1, 1.1); ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1); ax.set_zlim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax.set_xlabel("X_AXIS"); ax.set_ylabel("Y_AXIS"); ax.set_zlabel("Z_AXIS")
ax.legend();



timerTickInterval = 1000
ani = FuncAnimation(f1, timerTick_Event, interval=timerTickInterval)
plt.show()
```